# Use regexp to filter for question mark (?) parameter in url and add either ? or &

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string

I have this:

```
var searchString = action +  ?  + 'search=' + search + '&filter='
```

the `action` variable could either already have a `?parameter` or could not have one.

therefore I need to test action if it already contains a `?` and if so append &search. Otherwise I need to use `?search`

Any idea how to solve that in an easy manner?

Comment: to be clear, `action` can contain the `?` character, or can it contain the `?` character plus a parameter (more characters) after?

Comment: it can contain both right! action could look like this
`something?param&param` or `something?param` or just `something` therefore I need to find out I append another `?` or not because it's not allowed to have two `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var searchString = action + ((action.indexOf('?') == -1) ? '?search=' : '&search=');
```

Or you can use the jquery Query Plug-in http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

Answer (score 4):

```
var searchString = action + (action.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'search=' + search + '&filter=';
```

Comment: I think you'll want to change `!=` to `==`. If there's no question mark, then you want a question mark. Otherwise, you'll want the ampersand. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var startChar = action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&',
    searchString = action +  startChar  + 'search=' + search + '&filter=';
```

Answer (score 0):

quick, not super readable way:

```
var hasQM = (/\?/).test(action);
var searchString = action + (!hasQM ? '?' : '&') + 'search=' + search + '&filter='
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "?somerandonmestuffhere";
alert((string.match(/[?].*/) || ["?" + string])[0])
var string = "somerandonmestuffhere";
alert((string.match(/[?].*/) || ["?" + string])[0])
```